# Why does alphanumeric id search not working properly in Java Swing?

Tags: java, mysql

I have a search field in Java swing to search Books. I have UI having text field jtxtSearch to enter values and one Field JCombobox for categories. Though it's working for all other fields but not for id search. However when having a pretext in the book id (eg: sp001) its working and populating on jtable. My code is as below.

```
 public List<Book> searchBookBy(String search, String field){
    List<Book> results = new ArrayList<Book>();
    String sql = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    if(field.equalsIgnoreCase("id")){
        if(search.length() == 0) search = "0";
            sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE id = " + search;
        }else{
            sql = "SELECT * FROM books WHERE " + field + " LIKE '%" + search + "%'";
       }
```

After this is my try and catch to set variable id etc. The DB is MySQL.

Comment: It's not the problem, but [let me introduce you to my friend Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/). That code has a **major** problem unrelated to your question that you need to fix.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!), have a look around, and read through the [help], esp. [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) I also recommend Jon Skeet's [Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and [Question Checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). What is the structure of the table? The type of the `id` column? What is the value of `search` when it doesn't work. What rows are you expecting to match, and which ones match instead?

Comment: Your indentation suggests that you may missed `{` before `search = "0";`, without it `else` isn't alternation for second (nested) `if` condition but first (outer) `if`. Use proper editor with indentation/formatting tool, use that tool to see how your code really looks like.

Comment: The type of id column is varchar. When search with any id value its not working, except blank will give me id with pre-text (sp001, sp002 etc). Also when other columns like title, author etc.. its working.